# TextFormField Flutter not changing appropriately

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a form that I would like to be updated programatically from another widget is pressed. To test this I made the label text update with the same text and this worked as expected.

For some reason the inital value is not updated even though in debugging it does show the string to be the correct value. I added a controller to handle the text but i still don't understand why the initial value was not working the way I thought it would.

```
new TextFormField(
          key: _orderAddEditOrderFormKey,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: order.order == null ? 'Order' : order.order),
          initialValue: order.order == null ? "" : order.order,
        ),

setState(() {
            isBuildOrderUsed = true;
            if (this.order == null) {
              this.order = new Order(order: order);
            } else {
              this.order.order = order;
            }
          });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because the `initialValue` is set in the `initState` with the`TextEditingController` so you can not update that value, it is just the 'initial value'.

Check the source code of the `TextFormField` :

```
     @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        if (widget.controller == null) {
          _controller = new TextEditingController(text: widget.initialValue);
        } else {
          widget.controller.addListener(_handleControllerChanged);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense. So calling the setState doesn't call for a new state?

Comment: Calling setState rebuild the widget , build method

Comment: I am facing the same issue. setState(() {  }); with new value does not change the initialValue at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can open a new question and I will help you @LiveRock

Answer (score 1):

The only way to change the initialtext of a TextFormField is to use a TextEditingController() like so:

```
final _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

_textEditingController.addListener(_textEditingControllerListener);

void _textEditingControllerListener() {
    _textEditingController.text = newValue;
}
```