# setState does not update TextFormField when use initialValue

Tags: flutter

everyone.

I am using Form and TextFieldForm without any own TextEditController. Have 3 TextFieldForm (Value_1, Value_2, Total) with initial values. When i am editing first one, the Total textfield should contain result of calculation . To update widget i am using setState. The problem that variable _total and Text widget always has a correct calculation value, but the Total textfield does not want to update.

why? is it posible to do without using own TextEditController?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: TestForm(),
    );
  }
}

class TestForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestFormState createState() => _TestFormState();
}

class _TestFormState extends State<TestForm> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();

  int _value1 = 0;
  int _value2 = 20;
  int _total = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('rebuild');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('test form')),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: _value1.toString(),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Value_1',
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _total = int.parse(value) * _value2;
                    print('total: ' + _total.toString());
                  });
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: _value2.toString(),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                 decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Value_2',
                ),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: _total.toString(),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                 decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Total',
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Text('total: ' + _total.toString()),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Because its just an initial value, it not the value you set to TextFormField, maybe setState only rebuild Widget but not the initial value of it. try this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715534/textformfield-flutter-not-changing-appropriately)

Comment: no, it is not possible - use `controller` property instead of `initialValue`

Comment: btw what is wrong with using `TextEditController`? is your code more complex, not readable?

Comment: nothing wrong with TextEditController, but it´s a little bit strange for me use TextFormField with default controller without any easy option use this controller for managing values. 20 fields in form = 20 own controllers, it´s too complex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TextFormField Flutter not changing appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715534/textformfield-flutter-not-changing-appropriately)

Comment: You should add `Key` to your `TextFormField`. See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58348965/flutter-textformfield-not-updating-value-on-rebuild

Answer (score 128):

If you have a reactive data source, aka data that can change based on either network updates or other data, one hack that worked for me was to use a [`Key`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html).

By making a `Key` of the reactive data (`toString()`), the form field will change every time the `Key` changes.

So in this case you could do:

```
TextFormField(
  key: Key(_total.toString()), // <- Magic!
  initialValue: _total.toString(),
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Total',
  ),
),
```

Comment: If you have multiple TextFormFields you could end up with a key collision. UniqueKey seems to be a solution. Updates are really slow, I'm updating every time the user moves an object. Using a controller doesn't really make a performance difference...

Answer (score 5):

I used something as simple as this:

```html
TextFormField(
 controller:  TextEditingController()..text = '23232',
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Total',
  ),
),
```

Comment: This is not the correct way to do this. It will not `dispose()` of the `TextEdiingController`.

Comment: One way around this would be to [useTextEditingController](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_hooks/latest/flutter_hooks/useTextEditingController-constant.html) from flutter_hooks.