# Flutter, setstate doesn't working when update firebase data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, textformfield

I have declared var valueName; before my widget builder and after I set it with Firebase document value:     valueName = widget.item.name;
Then, i used valueName for initial value of a TextFormField and a setState in onChanged.
But when i use valueName in my update to Firestore function, it load the first old value. I can't update this value.

This is my TextFormField code:

```
TextFormField(
                      initialValue: valueName,
                      onChanged: (input) {
                        setState(() {
                          this.valueName = input;
                          print(valueName);
                        });
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                          filled: true,
                          icon: Icon(
                              Icons.person
                          ),
                          hintText: 'Inserisci il nome',
                          labelText: 'Nome'
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: Try removing this? I don’t think it’s useful here (i.e. valueName=input instead of this.valueName =input)

Comment: it doesn't even work that way

Comment: Ok good luck with that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setState does not update TextFormField when use initialValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58053956/setstate-does-not-update-textformfield-when-use-initialvalue)

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using TextEditingController ? you can use it to set your initial value as well as change the value anytime you want without setState.

```
class Temp extends StatefulWidget {
//constractor
// you are getting your value here
  @override
  _TempState createState() => _TempState ();
}

class _TempState extends State<Temp> with {
//declare here
var variable = widget.item.name;
// you can change this variable
```

Comment: i tried it right now and it doesn't work, it seems that if i declare a variable is equal to widget.item.name, it can't be changed by anything else

Comment: widget.item.name cant be changed..... u can declare another variable and then store the widget.item.name  in another variable shown like this.
widget.item.name is from another place. i dnt think u can change its value from here.
But there is a package named Get in PUb.dev you can try that
```
class Temp extends StatefulWidget {
//constractor
// you are getting your value here
  @override
  _TempState createState() => _TempState ();
}

class _TempState extends State<Temp> with {
//declare here
var variable = widget.item.name;
// you can change this variable
```